# Observation is not getting fired in Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift

Any ideas why Swift is not smart enough to infer the parameters passed to the observeWrapper function.

Code:

```
let implementation = QuestionJSONStrategy(name: questionGroup.course.rawValue)


    _ = observeWrapper(implementation)

    showQuestion()
}

func observeWrapper<T: NSObject & QuestionStrategy>(_ object: T) -> NSKeyValueObservation {
    return object.observe(\.questionIndex, options: .new) { _, change in
        guard let newValue = change.newValue else { return }
        print(newValue)
    }
}
```

**QuestionStrategy Protocol:**

```
@objc protocol QuestionStrategy :AnyObject {

    var questions :[Question] { get set}
    var questionIndex :Int { get set }

    init(name :String)

    func nextQuestion() -> Question
}
```

**QuestionJSONStrategy Class:**

```
@objc public class QuestionJSONStrategy :NSObject, QuestionStrategy  {

    var questions: [Question] = [Question]()
    @objc dynamic var questionIndex: Int = 0
```

Comment: Do paste your code instead of the screenshot

Comment: Don't know about that, but a heads-up; The docs recommend accessing the property in the value you are observing, not using `.new` and `change.newValue`. So instead, read `object.questionIndex` in the observer block.

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `let observable ... = implementation` line?

Comment: @dan I have removed that and now the error went away. But for reason the observation is not getting fired even if I change the questionIndex.